# jQuery based on different hyperlink click, add class to the target div and remove from other div sections

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to click on **different links** and based on that want to **add a class** on targeted div meanwhile also want to **remove added new class from other div section**.

I'm using here **'[data-getTarget~="one"]'** for get the hyperlink and target different div through **'[data-getTarget~="one"]'**

This code is working but I feel this can be create in better way.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 //var targetID = document.getElementsByClassName("stickyCalc");
  
 $('[data-getTarget~="one"]').click(function() {    
   $("[id^='one']").addClass( "mySpaceClass" );
   $("[id^='two']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" ); 
   $("[id^='three']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" ); 
   $("[id^='four']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" );
   $("[id^='five']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" ); 
  });
  
  $('[data-getTarget~="two"]').click(function() {    
   $("[id^='one']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" );
   $("[id^='two']").addClass( "mySpaceClass" ); 
   $("[id^='three']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" ); 
   $("[id^='four']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" );
   $("[id^='five']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" ); 
  });
  
  $('[data-getTarget~="three"]').click(function() {    
   $("[id^='one']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" );
   $("[id^='two']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" ); 
   $("[id^='three']").addClass( "mySpaceClass" ); 
   $("[id^='four']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" );
   $("[id^='five']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" ); 
  });
  
  $('[data-getTarget~="four"]').click(function() {    
   $("[id^='one']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" );
   $("[id^='two']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" ); 
   $("[id^='three']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" ); 
   $("[id^='four']").addClass( "mySpaceClass" );
   $("[id^='five']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" );
  });
  
  $('[data-getTarget~="five"]').click(function() {    
   $("[id^='one']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" );
   $("[id^='two']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" ); 
   $("[id^='three']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" ); 
   $("[id^='four']").removeClass( "mySpaceClass" );
   $("[id^='five']").addClass( "mySpaceClass" ); 
  });

});
```

```css
.mySpaceClass{
  margin:20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="stickyCalc">
<a href="#" data-getTarget="one"> One </a> | 
<a href="#" data-getTarget="two"> Two </a> | 
<a href="#" data-getTarget="three"> Three </a> | 
<a href="#" data-getTarget="four"> Four </a> | 
<a href="#" data-getTarget="five"> Five </a>
</div>


<hr>

<div id="one" style="background:green; padding:20px; color:white">
Headline 1
</div>

<div id="two" style="background:pink; padding:20px; color:white">
Headline 2
</div>

<div id="three" style="background:red; padding:20px; color:white">
Headline 3
</div>

<div id="four" style="background:black; padding:20px; color:white">
Headline 4
</div>

<div id="five" style="background:blue; padding:20px; color:white">
Headline 5
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a container div for the headlines you could run it like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.stickyCalc a').click(function() {

    $('#HeadlineContainer div').removeClass('mySpaceClass');
    $('#' + this.getAttribute('data-gettarget')).addClass("mySpaceClass")

  });

});
```

```css
.mySpaceClass{
  margin:20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="stickyCalc">
<a href="#" data-getTarget="one"> One </a> | 
<a href="#" data-getTarget="two"> Two </a> | 
<a href="#" data-getTarget="three"> Three </a> | 
<a href="#" data-getTarget="four"> Four </a> | 
<a href="#" data-getTarget="five"> Five </a>
</div>


<hr>
  <div id="HeadlineContainer">
<div id="one" style="background:green; padding:20px; color:white">
Headline 1
</div>

<div id="two" style="background:pink; padding:20px; color:white">
Headline 2
</div>

<div id="three" style="background:red; padding:20px; color:white">
Headline 3
</div>

<div id="four" style="background:black; padding:20px; color:white">
Headline 4
</div>

<div id="five" style="background:blue; padding:20px; color:white">
Headline 5
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add new class to all target divs as bellow --

```
<div class="stickyCalc">
<a href="#" data-getTarget="one"> One </a> | 
<a href="#" data-getTarget="two"> Two </a> | 
<a href="#" data-getTarget="three"> Three </a> | 
<a href="#" data-getTarget="four"> Four </a> | 
<a href="#" data-getTarget="five"> Five </a>
</div>


<hr>

<div class="target" id="one" style="background:green; padding:20px; color:white">
Headline 1
</div>

<div  class="target" id="two" style="background:pink; padding:20px; color:white">
Headline 2
</div>

<div  class="target" id="three" style="background:red; padding:20px; color:white">
Headline 3
</div>

<div  class="target" id="four" style="background:black; padding:20px; color:white">
Headline 4
</div>

<div  class="target" id="five" style="background:blue; padding:20px; color:white">
Headline 5
</div>
```

Then you can use below js code to achieve the required conventionality --

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //var targetID = document.getElementsByClassName("stickyCalc");
  $(".stickyCalc a").click(function(){

    $(".target").removeClass("mySpaceClass");
    var a =$(this).attr("data-getTarget");

    $("#"+a).addClass("mySpaceClass");
  });


});
```